What is the best way to create a clean 3D dotted line on a surface using a bezier curve?
I am drawing bezier curves onto 3d objects for a project. So far, I have been doing it like this:

Add a new bezier curve
Go into edit mode, select the draw tool, set depth to surface, and draw my curve with the mouse

After the curve is drawn, I go into Data --> Bevel, and create a round thickness of about .02m, so it looks like a noodle. I also then delete the original bezier curve vertices that were created when I added the curve. All that remains then is the bezier curve that I drew on the surface of my object.
My issue is that I need this curve to look like a 3D dotted line. I have tried working with array and curve modifiers, and I have tried adding a checkered texture to it and tweaking settings to work on transparency, but nothing has really worked yet. If I try to add a sphere with an array modifier and fit curve to the bezier curve, it only wants to align with the original curve, not the drawn curve.
I also installed the alpha version of blender 4.2 and used the grease pencil 3.0 so that I could use some of the new features, but that didn't work out either.
Any helpful tips out there for how I can create a clean 3D dotted line on a surface? Happy to provide more information/screenshots, etc. as needed. Thank you!

Dotted line from Bézier curve (Geometry Nodes)
I don't think this method satisfies the conditions you established, to be clean and probably perfectly on the surface. Here it is nonetheless.
You can use Geometry Nodes to delete one edge every 2 edges for example. In my example, I'm converting the initial Bézier curve to a mesh. Deleting a vertex/point on a curve doesn't create a gap, instead the curve would still be connected.
I can't say it's the best way, but it's a simple one. Here is the node setup you can use :

The parameters you should tweak for your case are :

Length : this is the resolution of the curve at the very beginning. In my case, this is also the length of one dot. You could change that with a little bit of math.
Radius : this is the thickness of the line.
Dot spacing : a custom input which let you choose the spacing of the dots.

This methods works well if you don't mind the cylindrical shape of the line elements. If you want the line to be flat, it would be achievable with Geometry Nodes but would require some more nodes.
You may want to increase the Offset of the curve Draw tool, in the N panel, so that the curve doesn't sink too much inside the mesh.

Finally, an example of use and the blend file.

Blend file


Hello, and thank you so much for taking the time to respond and provide pics + a gif. I am working on implementing this now. Just one point of clarification - can you expand on what you did with the "Add" and "Floored modulo" nodes? I'm fairly new and not sure exactly which nodes to search for to add those to the tree.

I found them in Math nodes and was able to connect the rest. This is a great solution, thank you so much!
